# Help needed for question on set generators.

Tags: group-theory

In the book by Stephan Foldes, titled: Fundamental structures of Algebra & Discrete Mathematics; in section 1.3 terminology is given for generation using their non-algorithmic, syntax-free concept: 
[image: terminology]  
The concept of intersection leads us to general algebraic tools of great
importance : closure systems, closure operators, and generators. 
Let $n$ be any natural number, $U$ any set, & $A\subseteq U$. The set  $C=\{A \subseteq U : f(x) \in A, \ \forall x \in A^n \}$ is a closure system on $U$, if $U \in C$ and the intersection of each nonempty subset of $C$ 
belongs to $C$.
 The members of $C$  are said to be closed under the function $f$. 
Clearly for every subset $A$ of $U$, the intersection of all closed super-sets of $A$ is closed. We denote it by $\bar{A}$ and call it the closure of $A$ in $C$. Obviously $A$ is a subset of $A$ and $A$ is the smallest closed 
super-set of $A$ (i.e., $A\subset K$ for any closed super-set $K$ of $A$). Further, if $A\subset B$ are both subsets of $U$, then every closed super-set of $B$ is also a super-set of $A$, from which it follows that $A\subset B$. Finally, the closure of a closed set is always itself.

For instance, let $U = ω$, and let \ be the function $f$ mapping each $n  \subset  ω$ to its successor $n+1$. 
Then the closed sets are those of the form $ω \\$ \ $m$ with natural numbers $m$. 
Every such closed set $ω \\$ \ $m$ is generated by its first element $m$. 
Observe that the set of all closure systems on a set $U$ is itself a 
closure system on $P(U)$. 
A function \ from $U^n$ to $U$ is called an n-ary operation on $U$ (in particular nullary, unary, binary, ternary, quaternary, for $n = 0,1,2,3,4$).
 
 
[image: Q.7]

Below is my attempt to **Q. 11**, of the given section's exercise:

Q.11 Show that for any finite set $S$ there is a permutation group $G$ 
on $S$ that is generated by a single $g\in G$ and such that Card $G = 
$Card $S$. Find examples of permutation groups $G$ not generated 
by any single $g \in G$. 
Ans.: $g$ can be a single permutation, taken as the initial configuration, from 

 which by shuffling all other permutations can be found; although do not know how to specify (except, by an algorithm) a function for the same.
**Unable to understand why a single $g$ not able to generate other permutation groups in $G$.**

Comment: Please avoid relying extensively on images; they are not searchable, screen readers cannot read them, they don't always display properly. I can barely make out the words in your images.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The text is stated in its crux in the OP, also if you click on image; a full-page view with bigger font appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, assume $S=\{1, \ldots, n\}$.
Let $G$ be the cyclic group generated by $g=(1, \ldots, n)$.

We have $g^n=g^0$ and $g^i \ne g^j$ where $i \ne j, |i-j|<n$. Hence $card(G)=card(S).$

As for an example where it is not generated by a single generator, consider the dihedral group of which both rotations and reflections are needed.

Comment: Seems that a simple mapping (due to equi-cardinality of group actions & set elements) is not enough constraint. I do not know how to express such constraint, but there must be some mechanism to find, on the basis of group actions' properties; might be if they all are in the same equivalence class or not.Then only one set of group actions is divided into two or more classes, and hence needs different sets for each class of group actions.

Comment: Please comment on the above, if not meaningless.

Comment: I do not know what constraint you are talking about.

Comment: I could not find a better term than constraint, to express the fact that the group actions' equi-cardinality with set $S$ is not enough to have single generator for the dihedral group of which both rotations and reflections are needed.

Comment: the second part of the question didn't impost any cardinality constraint isn't it? they just want examples not generated by a single $g$.

Comment: I expected the statement: 'permutation group $G$ on $S$', implied equi-cardinality of $G$ and $S$. But, yes you are correct as the second part does not imply the continuation of the first part. But, I feel that if $G$ needs multiple (let, $n\geq 2$) generators, even then the cardinality of $G$ has to be the same as the sum of cardinalities of the different sets $S_0, S_1, \cdots, S_{n-1}$; such that $g_0$ applies to $S_0$, $g_1$ applies to $S_1$,..,$g_{n-1}$ applies to $S_{n-1}$. If not, then please give me a counter-example.

Comment: I want to add to my last comment that $|S|=|G|$, even if $n\geq 2$, where $n$ is the number of equivalence classes of $G$.

Comment: I can't understand your question, what are those $S_i$? $S$ is fixed.

Comment: I mean that $S$ has been split into $n(\geq 2)$ parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104996/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).